# Install plone front-page content from setup profile of site policy product add-on

Tags: plone

Plone's base setup profile -- in Products.CMFPlone.setuphandlers.setupPortalContent() -- queries for a registered view named 'plone-frontpage-setup' to obtain body text for the front-page populated into a new site.

An add-on site policy product package could register a view (with, unfortunately, no layer interface constraining it) to override the default -- however, this would be applicable to all new sites created in an instance.

Is there a *pluggable* way to use GenericSetup extension profiles to install new front-page content on add-on installation, or does this require a DIY setup handler / import-step?

Reading the source for the base setupPortalContent(), it seems that this was set up for ease of out-of-the-box i18n, but not (yet) for pluggable extension by add-ons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried content generation using Generic Setup?

The following example should reset the content generated by setupPortalContent():

1. Add folder named `structure` under your site policy product's default profile folder (*e.g. src/my.site.policy/my/site/policy/profiles/default/structure/*).
2. Under that folder, add a new file named `.delete` with content

   ```
   events
   front-page
   Members
   news
   ```
3. Under the same folder, add a new file named `.objects` with content

   ```
   front-page,Document
   ```
4. Still under the same folder, add a new file named `front-page` with content

   ```
   id: front-page
   title: Foo
   description: Bar
   Content-Type: text/html

   <p>Hello World!</p>
   ```

The new Plone site created with this policy should contain only the front-page described above. (Note that the new front-page has the initial state of its default workflow, which is *private* by default.)

The easiest way to experiment with content generation further, I think, is to just create something, export `Content`-step from `portal_setup` and examine the results. Also the [Generic Setup Quick Reference](http://www.sixfeetup.com/technologies/plone-content-management/quick-reference-cards/generic_setup.pdf) by Six Feet Up gives an overview for content generation support in Generic Setup.